# Can i create animated resize content as in react native docs

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I want to create the same animation content but I don't know how to do this. Using just `KeyboardAvoidingView` don't do that effect

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/keyboardavoidingview.html

Answer (score 0):

It's not exactly component you want to animate. But this [article](https://moduscreate.com/blog/expanding-and-collapsing-elements-using-animations-in-react-native/) could help you.
You'll find the GitHub repository there.

Don't miss to check [official doc for animations](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/animated.html).